# Pandas: Pivoting column headers to row labels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have extracted data from a website using the following:

```
import pandas as pd  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

stat_dict={'Disposals' : 0,
           'Kicks' : 1,
           'Marks' : 2,
           'Handballs' : 3,
           'Goals' : 4,
           'Behinds' : 5,
           'Hitouts' : 6,
           'Tackles' : 7,
           'Rebounds' : 8,
           'Inside50s' : 9,
           'Clearances': 9,
           'Clangers' : 10,
           'FreesFor' : 11,
           'FreesAgainst' : 12,
           'ContestedPosessions' : 13,
           'UncontestedPosesseions' : 14,
           'ContestedMarks' : 15,
           'MarksInside50' : 16,
           'OnePercenters' : 17,
           'Bounces' : 18,
           'GoalAssists' : 19,
           'Timeplayed' : 20}

team_lower_case='fremantle'
player1="Fyfe, Nat"
stat_required='Disposals'
rounds=8



tables = pd.read_html("https://afltables.com/afl/stats/teams/" +str(team_lower_case)+"/2018_gbg.html")

for df in tables:
    df.drop(df.columns[rounds+1:], axis=1, inplace=True)   # remove unwanted columns
    df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)    # remove extra index level


stat_table=tables[stat_dict[stat_required]]

player_stat=stat_table[stat_table["Player"]==player1]
```

Which produces the following:

```
      Player    R1    R2    R3    R4    R5    R6    R7    R8
8  Fyfe, Nat  22.0  29.0  38.0  25.0  43.0  27.0  33.0  36.0
```

**How can I set the index to the data in the column 'Player'?**

**How can I pivot the column headers to become row labels and vice-versa?**
The output I am looking for would be as follows:

```
 Round  Fyfe, Nat  Neale,Lachie
    R1        22             37
    R2        29             28
```

The end output I would like to get is a scatter plot that plots on the x-axis the column headers e.g. R1, R2 etc... and on the y-axis the row data.

I feel like I should be able to plot the data frame directly, but the only way I have had success is by doing the following:

```
for round, disp in player_stat.iterrows():
    player1_list=[]
    player1_list.append(disp)

plt.style.use('ggplot')
plt.scatter(range(1,rounds+1), player1_list, label=player1)
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.title("Disposals per round")
plt.xlabel("Rounds")
plt.ylabel("Disposals")
plt.ylim(ymin=0)
```

It seems like I should use .transpose, which is close to what I want and outputs the following:

```
                8
Player  Fyfe, Nat
R1             22
R2             29
R3             38
R4             25
R5             43
R6             27
R7             33
R8             36
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with traspose by [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
stat_table=tables[stat_dict[stat_required]].set_index('Player').T
```

---

```
print (stat_table)
Player  Ballantyne, Hayden  Banfield, Bailey  Blakely, Connor  \
R1                    10.0              12.0             17.0   
R2                    11.0              14.0             30.0   
R3                    18.0              11.0             21.0   
R4                     9.0              17.0             16.0   
R5                    14.0              18.0             23.0   
R6                     6.0              14.0             31.0   
R7                    14.0              20.0             21.0   
R8                    11.0              12.0             35.0   

Player  Brayshaw, Andrew  Cerra, Adam  Cox, Brennan  Crowden, Mitch  \
R1                  12.0          NaN           NaN             NaN   
R2                  16.0          9.0           NaN            11.0   
R3                   7.0         10.0           NaN            13.0   
R4                  11.0          7.0           NaN            15.0   
R5                  17.0         15.0           NaN            17.0   
R6                  14.0         11.0           NaN            11.0   
R7                  14.0         18.0           8.0             8.0   
R8                  16.0         14.0          12.0            10.0   

Player  Duman, Taylin  Fyfe, Nat  Hamling, Joel   ...    Pearce, Danyle  \
R1                NaN       22.0            NaN   ...              12.0   
R2                NaN       29.0           12.0   ...               NaN   
R3                NaN       38.0           11.0   ...               NaN   
R4                NaN       25.0           16.0   ...               NaN   
R5               15.0       43.0           11.0   ...               NaN   
R6               12.0       27.0            9.0   ...               NaN   
R7                8.0       33.0           12.0   ...               NaN   
R8               15.0       36.0           18.0   ...              18.0   

Player  Ryan, Luke  Sandilands, Aaron  Sheridan, Tom  Sutcliffe, Cameron  \
R1            16.0               16.0            NaN                17.0   
R2            22.0               10.0            NaN                 NaN   
R3            21.0               14.0           14.0                 NaN   
R4            14.0               15.0           11.0                 NaN   
R5            21.0                9.0            NaN                 NaN   
R6            18.0               10.0            NaN                 NaN   
R7            13.0               11.0            NaN                 NaN   
R8            27.0               13.0            NaN                 NaN   

Player  Taberner, Matthew  Tucker, Darcy  Walters, Michael  Wilson, Nathan  \
R1                   20.0           12.0              18.0            15.0   
R2                   16.0            NaN              26.0            23.0   
R3                   18.0            NaN              23.0            18.0   
R4                   19.0           15.0              21.0            14.0   
R5                    6.0           17.0              18.0            27.0   
R6                    NaN           17.0               2.0            15.0   
R7                    NaN           15.0               NaN            19.0   
R8                    NaN           13.0               NaN             NaN   

Player  Totals  
R1       358.0  
R2       399.0  
R3       387.0  
R4       362.0  
R5       407.0  
R6       356.0  
R7       346.0  
R8       404.0  

[8 rows x 32 columns]
```

And then is possible select column by `player1`:

```
player_stat=stat_table[player1]
print (player_stat)
R1    22.0
R2    29.0
R3    38.0
R4    25.0
R5    43.0
R6    27.0
R7    33.0
R8    36.0
Name: Fyfe, Nat, dtype: float64
```

And last `plot`:

```
plt.scatter((range(1,rounds+1)), stat_table[player1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Player':['Fyfe, Nat','Neale,Lachie'],
                'r1':[22,29],
                'r2': [27, 25],
                'r3': [30, 21]})

print df
         Player  r1  r2  r3
0     Fyfe, Nat  22  27  30
1  Neale,Lachie  29  25  21

df = df.set_index('Player').T
print df
```

Output:

```
Player  Fyfe, Nat  Neale,Lachie
r1             22            29
r2             27            25
r3             30            21
```